# ActionBarSherlock: display/move spinner on left side using actionbarSherlock [solution:use NavigationList]

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want spinner on left side in sherlock action bar but due to standard behavior it is coming on right side .[see attach image[image: ]]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,i have done this by using navigationlist instead of manually adding spinner in menu.xml:

**1. Items require in list must define in array.xml as:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   
    <string-array name="dashboardItemList">
        <item>Dashboard</item>
        <item>Downloads</item>
        <item>Revenues</item>
        <item>Ads</item>
        <item>Rankings</item>
        <item>Reviews</item>
        <item>Events</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**2. Call navigationList Method in on createMenuOption**

@Override

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    setNavigationList();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**3. Define NavigationMethod,and get strings arrays from array.xml. And set built in layout sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item for NavigationMode.**

```
public void setNavigationList() {
              arrayItemsForDropdown = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dashboardItemList);
              Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
              ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,R.array.dashboardItemList,              R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
              list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
              getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
              getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
}
```

** 4. Now give implementation as per your choice in onNavigationItemSelected Method **

```
@Override

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

    if (arrayItemsForDropdown[itemPosition].equals("Dashboard")) {
        downloadIcon.setVisible(false);
        DashboardFragment dashboardFragment = new DashboardFragment();
        showFragment(R.id.fragmentContainer, dashboardFragment, "dashboard");
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out);

    } else if (arrayItemsForDropdown[itemPosition].equals("Downloads")) {
        Log.d("Spinner", "downloadClicked");
        showProgressDialog();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               checkDownloadsData();
            }
        }).start();
        

    }
              // skipping further else parts.....

    return true;
}
```

:) And navigationlist bydefault align to left in ActionBarSherlock. Check snapshot.

[image]